# C++ Linker Error with DirectX SDK

Tags: c++, linker, directx, directx-11

I'm trying, desperately, to get into C++ programming with DirectX. It's been a steep uphill battle, and I've only written a couple of lines of code. Most of my battles have been with the linker. So far, I have this in my header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "resource.h"
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

IDXGISwapChain *swapChain;
ID3D11Device *device;
ID3D11DeviceContext *deviceContext;

void InitializeDirect3D(HWND hWnd);
void CleanDirect3D(void);
```

And in the source file:

```
// InitializingDX.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "InitializingDX.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_INITIALIZINGDX, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_INITIALIZINGDX));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_INITIALIZINGDX));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_INITIALIZINGDX);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    scd.BufferCount = 1;
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
    scd.Windowed = true;

    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &scd, &swapChain, &device, NULL, &deviceContext);
}
```

It breaks on that last line, saying "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48 references in function void*_cdecl InitD3D(struct HWND__*)" (?InitD3D@@YAXPAUHWND__@@@Z)".

I don't know what's wrong here, the #includes work to link the D3D libraries in, and the program builds or executes up until it gets to that line. Any help you guys could give would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is that the only error you get?

Comment: Well that, and "1 unresolved external symbol"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, if I omit the x64 library, it works. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

What version of the DirectX SDK do you have? The latest up to date SDK can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6812) .

Also, make sure you are linking to the correct library path. By default it is

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86;$(LibraryPath)`

I attempted to compile you code (I have to comment out the additional `#includes` that were unavailable, and had to `#define` some of the ID variables, and it was about to compile with no linker errors.

Comment: Is that on my solution Properties, under Additional Dependencies in my Input under Linker? I'm pretty new to all this, and it's the linking that's really screwing my around. Soo easy in C#...

Comment: @Jack: Looks to me like who/whatever is trying to teach you is an incompetent baboon.

Comment: Mmm....I think the tutorial I found (http://www.directxtutorial.com/Tutorial11/B-A/BA5.aspx#still) assumes a relativaly high-level understanding of C++, which I don't have. I'm still unable to pinpoint exactly what type of Visual Studio project I'm supposed to be using with this...

Comment: If is an .exe and not a library you are trying to create then if you look in Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System should have the field "SubSystem" selected as "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" from the drop down

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is that this function does not exist for Metro applications. If you are using the vNext preview versions, then the function will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the d3d11 libs from older SDKs don't define this GUID. Here is a workaround in case you are not ready to switch SDKs yet...

Add the following lines to your code (in the cpp file where you need it)...

```
const GUID __declspec(selectany) IID_ID3D11Device = { 
    0xdb6f6ddb, 
    0xac77, 
    0x4e88, 
    {0x82, 0x53, 0x81, 0x9d, 0xf9, 0xbb, 0xf1, 0x40}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try linking with DXGUID.LIB

```
#pragma comment (lib, "dxguid.lib")
```

You haven't mentioned which version of the compiler you are using. If you are using VS 2012 or VS 2013, then you need to take some extra steps to use old stuff like D3DX11 from the legacy DirectX SDK without getting weird errors. See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). If you are using VS 2010 or later, you have to manually add the references to the DirectX SDK to your VC++ directories--it's not automatic.

You should take a look at the latest version of the Direct3D 11 tutorial (Win32 desktop version) on [MSDN Code Gallery](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef). You may also find [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) useful, as well as the article [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx).